# Java multi-threading thread pooling behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Java multi-threading from John Purcell's courses and have a question in regards to Thread Pooling. I understand from what I have learned so far that execution time of threads in multi-threading is hardware-processor dependent. I have used the ExecutorService utility in Java multi-threading in one of John's examples and here is the code. What is that exact phenomena that causes these thread pools to execute differently on different computers?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Processor implements Runnable {

  private int count = 0;

  public Processor (int count){
    this.count = count;
  }

  public void run(){
    System.out.println("Started: " + count);

    try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Completed: " + count);

  }

}

public class Pooling{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    executor.submit(new Processor(i));
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    System.out.println("All tasks submitted...");

    try{
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("All tasks have been completed. ");

  }

}
```

This code prints out the following pool on one computer (Win 7, 32-bit, 2M Cache, 1.86 GHz)

```
Started: 0
Started: 1
All tasks submitted...
Completed: 0
Started: 2
Completed: 1
Started: 3
Completed: 3
Started: 4
Completed: 2
Completed: 4
All tasks have been completed. 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

and prints the following pool on another computer (Win 8.1, 64-bit, 3M cache, 2.7 GHz)

```
All tasks submitted...
Started: 1
Started: 0
Completed: 1
Started: 2
Completed: 0
Started: 3
Completed: 2
Started: 4
Completed: 3
Completed: 4
All tasks have been completed. 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Comment: There really is no way to answer this question.  Even if you ran it multiple times on the same computer you would get different results based on scheduling of the threads.  To make it interesting, create a fixed thread pool with more threads than you have logical cores, and then add twice that number of runnables to execute.  It'll become even less predictable.

Comment: OS scheduling? Different loads, different start times, etc -- these tiny (and unimportant) things will affect ordering of executions (and ordering itself is unimportant as long as you don't need inter-thread communication).

Comment: There is no guarantee that threads will start and complete in the same order consistently, even when testing on the same computer